# Access-Control-Allow-Origin -  php

Tags: php

Вот скрипт:

1) **a.php**

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

include_once "./q.php";

$res = new MyClass($_GET['q']);

print $res->data;
```

2) **q.php**

```
class MyClass {

    public function MyMethod () {

        $get = file_get_contents("http://sdfdsfsdfdsfsd");
        $decode = json_decode($get, TRUE); // TRUE for in array format

        foreach($decode['SearchResponse']['Web']['Results'] as $res)
        {
            echo('<div id="res">');
            echo "<p><div id='desc'>".$res['Description']." - <a href='".$res['Url']."' rel='nofollow'  target='_blank'>read more</a></div></p>";
            echo('</div>');
        }

    }
}
```

При обращение к скрипту **a.php** выдает ошибку:

> [20-Oct-2014 19:29:09 Europe/Helsinki]
> PHP Notice:  Undefined property:
> MyClass::$data in

Ругается на эту строку:

```
print $res->data;
```

Как исправить?

Comment: Так в ошибке чёрным по белому написано, что не так, никакой тайны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то вот так, подробностей вопроса я не увидел:

```
class MyClass {

    public $data;

    function __construct ($data) {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function MyMethod () {

        // тут твой код;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас нет ни метода, ни параметра data. Параметры объявляются сразу после объявления класса и до объявления функции (она же метод).

Comment: Можете показать на моем примере, как надо?